# cairo pdf bounding box

Tags: c++, pdf, cairo, bounding-box

I am using cairo graphics with C++ and outputting to pdf. However, when the graphic is included in a document (LaTeX) there is too much white space around the figure. How does one program cairo to put a tight bounding box around the figure?

Answer (score 1):

You pass the width and height that you need when you call cairo_pdf_surface_create(). After that it is very much your own choice how much of that space you want to fill with drawing. If you ask Cairo to draw all the way to the edges, it will.

The only other thing I can think of is that LaTeX adds a border. This, however, is outside my area of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
https://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Recording-Surfaces.html
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <cairo.h>
#include <cairo-svg.h>
#include <cairo-ps.h>
#include <cairo-pdf.h>

void star(cairo_t* cr, double radius)
  {
  double theta = 0.8*M_PI;
  cairo_save(cr);
  cairo_move_to(cr, 0.0, -radius);
  for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
    cairo_rotate(cr, theta);
    cairo_line_to(cr, 0.0, -radius);
    }
  cairo_fill(cr);
  cairo_restore(cr);
  }

int main()
  {
  // set recording surface
  cairo_surface_t* record = cairo_recording_surface_create(CAIRO_CONTENT_COLOR_ALPHA, NULL);
  cairo_t* cr = cairo_create(record);
  // start image
  cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); // set color to black
  star(cr, 100);                           // big star
  cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // set color to blue
  star(cr, 95);                            // smaller star
  // end image
  double x0, y0, width, height;
  cairo_recording_surface_ink_extents(record, &x0, &y0, &width, &height);
  // printf("Size %lf by %lf at (%lf, %lf)\n", width, height, x0, y0);

  // create pdf image
  const char* outputfile = "bb.pdf";
  cairo_surface_t* target = cairo_pdf_surface_create(outputfile, width, height);
  cairo_t*         crt    = cairo_create(target);
  // copy recorded image to target and paint
  cairo_set_source_surface(crt, record, -x0, -y0);
  cairo_paint(crt);
  // clean up
  cairo_destroy (cr);
  cairo_surface_destroy (record);
  cairo_destroy (crt);
  cairo_surface_destroy (target);
  }
```